# jQuery conflict a.fn.cssOriginal=a.fn.css and a[c].css("box-sizing")

Tags: jquery

I have two jQuery files that were conflicting with each other. I was getting the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object 0px has no method 'css'
```

After much tweaking and tinkering, I figured out how to solve this. However, I think this is not a proper solution, and I would like to get feedback on an alternate proper solution.

The files are jQuery plugin files from 1) from a template and 2) from a slideshow; both resize containers and other elements when the screen is resized.

The source of the problem is that the slideshow jquery plugin declares:

a.fn.cssOriginal=a.fn.css;

and I can read the error to lines of the template's jquery file whenever a[c].css("box-sizing"), or similar, is being called.

**I solved this by replacing .css for .cssOriginal** throughout the template's jquery functions file. But I feel uneasy. First of all, the slideshow will only be used in some pages.

How could prevent the tempalte's .css calls be affected from slideshow plugin file?

All of the jQuery files from the slideshow include a jQuery.noConflict(); at the end.

From the template, this section of the code was the source of the conflict:

```
e.matchHeight = function (a, c, f) {
    var j = e(window),
        h = a && b[a];

    if (!h) {
        var h = b[a] = {
            id: a,
            elements: c,
            deepest: f,
            match: function () {
                var a = this.revert(),
                    b = 0;

                e(this.elements).each(function () {
                    b = Math.max(b, e(this).outerHeight())
                }).each(function (c) {
                    var d = "outerHeight";
                    "border-box" == a[c].css("box-sizing") && (d = "height");

                    var g = e(this),
                        c = a[c],
                        d = c.height() + (b - g[d]());

                    c.css("min-height", d + "px")
                })
            },
            revert: function () {
                var a = [],
                    b = this.deepest;

                e(this.elements).each(function () {
                    var c = b ? e(this).find(b + ":first") : e(this);
                    a.push(c.css("min-height", ""))
                });

                return a

            },
            remove: function () {
                j.unbind("resize orientationchange", k);
                this.revert();
                delete b[this.id]
            }
        }, k = function () {
            h.match()
        };

        j.bind("resize orientationchange", k)
    }

    return h
};
```

and from the slide show, this section of the code is the source of the problem:

```
a.fn.cssOriginal=a.fn.css;

    a.fn.css=function(c,d){

        var e=this,f={};
        if(typeof c=="string")if(d)f[a.camelCase(c)]=d;
        else return e.cssOriginal(c);
        else f=c;
        f=a.cssPropertySupporter(f);
        var g=a("body").data("cssPerspective");
        if(f.transform)a.each(b,function(a,b){var c=b+(b?"T":"t")+"ransform";
        var d=f.transform;
        f[c]=(g&&!/perspective/gi.test(d)?"perspective("+g+") ":"")+d});
        e.cssOriginal(f); 
        return e

    }
```

Thank you

Comment: Could you post a working demo?

Comment: Well... broken I guess, so we can fix it.

Comment: @Charlie I posted the link, but since numeric I could not add the http:// for direct link

Comment: try enclosing d + "px" in single quote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are including slideshow jquery-plugin first and template jquery-plugin later in your page. If that is the case, can you include one liner java-script in between both plugins? That one liner script may contain something like below:

```
a.fn.css=a.fn.cssOriginal;
```

I have not tried it, but just give it a try as this should work.

Comment: This $.fn.css=a.fn.cssOriginal; and this $.fn.css=$.fn.cssOriginal;  work. Ideally, I would like to keep this within the slideshow code. So I am trying to place it at the end of the slideshow file...

Comment: Great that it works. You can also put this at end of slideshow plugin, or you can have another script being included just after slideshow plugin. See if what suits you the best.

Answer (score 0):

Are these scripts meant to work together?

From what I can tell, `var e` is set in both, so it's probably going to cause a problem between them.

I would suggest looking into a different slideshow plugin.